# Windows 7 - How to resolve “You need to have Ruby and Sass installed and in your PATH for this task to work” Warning?

Tags: ruby, sass, gruntjs, npm

Most answers and solutions are related to OSX, it is focused in Windows 7:

I have installed Grunt & Grunt CLI globally. Then I did a npm install inside a project folder to install all dependencies.

No problems so far, but as soon as I try to run the "grunt build" command, I get this warning in my project:

```
 Warning: You need to have Ruby and Sass installed and in your PATH for
 this task to work. More info:
 https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass Use --force 
 to continue.
```

Answer (score 9):

Ok. This worked for me:

1) Download Ruby from http://rubyinstaller.org/

2) When you install, check the 'PATH' option. This is the key.

3) Once installed, open the prompt (you can use interactive ruby) and write

> gem install sass

Now it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider that newbie people most of the time try to use these commands:

```
 npm install ruby
 npm install sass
```

It won't work.

Solution:

1. Download and install Ruby from here “http://rubyinstaller.org/”
2. Execute in a command prompt window “gem install sass”

Only downloading Ruby independently it works. If you try npm install ruby it won't work.

Hope it helps to solve this problem in your case.

Comment: [`npm install ruby`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ruby) installs "Helper methods from ruby ported to Node". It **does not** install Ruby, which is an entirely different programming language than Javascript.

Comment: thanks for that clarification, it helps to newbie guys.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the need of Ruby, you can try this:

```
npm uninstall --save grunt-contrib-sass
npm install --save node-sass grunt-sass
```

> Source:
> https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass/issues/229#issuecomment-281284894